# Generating a time plot of moving sum with a special conditions (sum of top 5 firms)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have firm data for a number of firms, each of which belongs to a particular sector with the following format:

```
structure(list(id = structure(c("350257", "500607", "351253", 
"320498", "351156", "360252", "360317", "360228", "380911", "381152"
), format.stata = "%6s"), year = structure(c(1980, 1980, 1980, 
1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    sector = structure(c("D", "D", "D", 
    "A", "A", "D", "D", "A", 
    "A", "A"), format.stata = "%8s"), sales = structure(c(1.13e+09, 
    83042221000, 46125269000, 40104358000, 10337892000, 285413525000, 
    24862547000, 99182761000, 154806013000, 2629392000), format.stata = "%12.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to compute and plot the sum of top 3 firms' sales (in order of sales amount) by each sector using the following formula.
`top3sales = (rank 1’s sales + rank 2’s sales + rank 3’s sales) / (sum of all firms' sales in the sector)`

Eventually I want to plot the moving sum for each sector on the same plane using something like:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y= Top3sales)) + geom_line()
```

But first off I don't know how to find the sum of top 3 firms' sales each year by sector.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean you want group your data by `sector` and get the `top5sales` in each group?  Maybe your example is too small (<5 in each sector group).

Comment: I changed the condition to top 3 and just 2 secters.

Answer (score 1):

Is this your wanted?

```r
library(data.table)
df <- structure(list(id = structure(c("350257", "500607", "351253", 
"320498", "351156", "360252", "360317", "360228", "380911", "381152"
), format.stata = "%6s"), year = structure(c(1980, 1980, 1980, 
1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    sector = structure(c("D", "D", "D", 
    "A", "A", "D", "D", "A", 
    "A", "A"), format.stata = "%8s"), sales = structure(c(1.13e+09, 
    83042221000, 46125269000, 40104358000, 10337892000, 285413525000, 
    24862547000, 99182761000, 154806013000, 2629392000), format.stata = "%12.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

dt <- setDT(df)[,
  .(top3sales = sum(head(.SD[,sort(sales,decreasing = T)], 3)) / sum(sales)),
  by=.(year,sector)]
dt
#>    year sector top3sales
#> 1: 1980      D 0.9410029
#> 2: 1980      A 0.9577696
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is not so clear.  is this required?

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(year, sector) %>%
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(-sales)) %>%
  summarise(top3sales = sum(sales[rank <= 3])/sum(sales), .groups = 'drop')

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>    year sector top3sales
#>   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1  1980 A          0.958
#> 2  1980 D          0.941
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>